# AutoComplete characters as ( and }

Tags: c#, textbox

I am developing a simple text editor, and I'm having trouble doing the self add some character ... I did the following sample code, what I'm doing ... When I type the character, it does not add its corresponding char in current cursor position....

Another doubt, how can I make the program ignore the characters added when I type it again ...??

```
Dictionary<char, char> glbin = new Dictionary<char, char>
{
    {'(', ')'},
    {'{', '}'},
    {'[', ']'},
    {'<', '>'}
};

private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    int line = textBox1.GetLineFromCharIndex(textBox1.SelectionStart);
    int column = textBox1.SelectionStart - textBox1.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(line);

    if(glbin.ContainsKey(e.KeyChar))
        textBox1.Text.Insert(column, glbin[e.KeyChar].ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

String is immutable object, and Insert call on Text property produces new instance of string, which is not assigned anywhere.

And to ignore char you need to set KeyPressEventArgs Handled property to true (you would probably need inverse dictionary of closing chars).

You need to change your code to:

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    int index = textBox1.SelectionStart;
    if(glbin.ContainsKey(e.KeyChar))
    {
      var txt = textBox1.Text; // insert both chars at once
      textBox1.Text = txt.Insert(index, e.KeyChar + glbin[e.KeyChar].ToString());
      textBox1.Select(index + 1, 0);// position cursor inside brackets
      e.Handled = true;
    }
    else if (glbin.Values.Contains(e.KeyChar))
    {
      // move cursor forward ignoring typed char
      textBox1.SelectionStart = textBox1.SelectionStart + 1;
      e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if the code is then working as intended. When typing `(`, it'll insert `(` as the first character and `)` at the current cursor position, and change the cursor position to the beginning of the TextBox.

Comment: Really, it does not work perfectly .... the cursor back to the starting position of the textbox ...

Comment: Probably you can reposition cursor by calling Select(..), one moment I will update answer

Comment: Have something very strange ... if you test the code, you will notice that after you type the first character he creates everything right, but after adding it to the character ...

Comment: Added final version of handler which behaves correctly